# how to upload an excel sheet in google drive using java api

Tags: java, excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

In the *Google developers code*, method to *upload a spreadsheet* is given for `.net` but not `java` . Does any one know the sample code for this .  code on `how to convert an excel file to a spreadsheet and upload it` will also do .

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below url. It might help you

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361814/create-spreadsheet-using-google-spreadsheet-api-in-google-drive-java
```

Answer (score 0):

**login/OAuth2** The Google "DrEdit" tutorial is a good starting place for login/OAuth2 etc.

Upload: The only method I have seen uses **Google drive sdk**

Java example here: 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

An example of the convert, (in PHP) using the same API,
[Create a Google Drive Spreadsheet from a local CSV file via the Google Drive API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115468/create-a-google-drive-spreadsheet-from-a-local-csv-file-via-the-google-drive-api)